# Stripping MySQL queries of foreign accents

Tags: php, mysql, diacritics

I must admit that I am ignorant of php, and that my current script was inherited...

It queries a MySQL database with a `city` name and returns all instances it finds of that `city`.

I had a couple of problems: the first to do with hyphens (e.g. Stratford-upon-Avon); that has been solved with the addition of

```
$searchq = str_replace( '-', ' ', $searchq );
```

which allows me to enter the data in the database without hyphens.

My remaining problem has to do with foreign accent (in particular: acute, grave, circumflex, cedille, tilde). I tried a million functions, many that I found on this site and don't manage to get it to work.

the main php code of my current page is this

```
$searchq = filter_var("%{$_POST['keyword']}%", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); // Sanitize the string
```

$searchq = str_replace( '-', ' ', $searchq );

```
$sql = "SELECT Image, Chain, Country, City, Top as '', Medium as '', Low as '' FROM Chains WHERE Country LIKE ? OR City LIKE ?"; // Your query string

$prepare = $mysqli->prepare($sql); // Prepare your query string
$prepare->bind_param('ss', $searchq, $searchq); // Bind the placeholders to your search variables
// s = string | i = integer | d = double | b = blob
$prepare->execute(); // Execute the prepared statement
$prepare->store_result(); // Store the results for later checking
```

I have avoided coming to this forum as I understand that it is meant for advanced developers, and I am not one of them...

All the above code does is to DELETE the accented letter, rather than replacing it with the same letter without the accent

**EDIT**

How do I get Ollie Jones' attention again?

I am stuck, not knowing how to handle the script part

**Another EDIT**
When I enter this in the table SQL

ALTER TABLE Chains CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

I get this warning and nothing gets done...

#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

Comment: You are just fine here. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Why exactly do you want to get rid of all these special characters? Can't your database also contain them?

Comment: Take the French town 'Sèvres'. Like many others in the database (1000s) I don't want to have both with and without accents. So the database has 'Sevres' and if someone writes the correct word, at the moment the reply is "Nothing found"...

Comment: Let me add to the last comment about entering in the database with and without accents. Take the simple word 'Sèvres' (grave). Some like me might write 'Sévres' (acute). Others used to googling write 'Sevres' (no accent). That's the simple case. In more complicated you might have 2 different signs (grave and circumflex; acute and cedilla); then you will have some that are made up of two or three words, and  to make rooms for all the combinations and possible errors you end up with an enormous amount of work and confusion... The "easy" way out is to get a script to strip all accents.

Comment: Take 'résumé' or to make it more interesting 'tête-à-tête'....

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have 2 columns in the database, one for actual name with accents and diacritics and second without. Once someone enters a word you remove special characters in the code and searches if that entry exists (based on unaccented/slug column) and use it. That way you can display accented version and search by unaccented.

Comment: HiI have just added to my last post but was not accepted. take the compound word 'tête-à-tête'. You could end up with 30 different versions depending on error with accents (acute/grave instead of circumplex); puttind accents in one but not in the others; the 'a' with grave/acute ot without, etc etc.. In any case, what I need is to strip the accents from the words. How can that be done, please? besides, the database has already over 10000 records and I have no time to start all over again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This kind of question is entirely appropriate.

Comment: Why remove information from a name? Just sort out the searching to be more liberal with spelling and the input of data to be more rigorous,

Comment: How about using SOUNDEX for matching?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's character set and collation features are designed to handle this sort of thing correctly without the need for extra search columns.

For example, observe this little query:

```
select _utf8'résumé' COLLATE utf8_general_ci = _utf8'resume'
```

or, using the more modern utf8mb4 character set,

```
select _utf8mb4'résumé' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci = _utf8mb4'resume'
```

Both these queries find that `résumé` and `resume` are equal. It works for almost every European-language accented character.

These queries contains two character string constants explicitly created as unicode strings. It then compares them using the *case_insensitive* collation. In that collation, the upper and lower case forms of e-acute and e-grave are all considered the same.

How do you get this to work with your database?

1. make sure the character set of your place-name columns (`City`, `Country`) are set to `utf8`, or better yet, the more robust and modern `utf8mb4`.
2. make sure the default collation for those tables is the case-insensitive collation for the  character set you choose.
3. Just do your queries. You don't need anything special.  For example, `WHERE City = 'Sèvres'` and `WHERE City = 'sevres'` will yield identical results. This is perfect for users accustomed to Google-type search.

Before altering your table make a backup copy in case you screw something up.

```
CREATE TABLE chains_backup SELECT * FROM chains
```

Then use this sort of command to change the columns in your table.

```
  alter table chains
       modify City  varchar(255)
                    character set utf8mb4
                    collate utf8mb4_general_ci
```

In place of `varchar(255)` you need to use the actual data type of the column. You didn't tell us what that is, so I'm guessing.

The default collation you choose for each colum is baked in to the indexes. So not only will your diacritic-insensitive searches be accurate, they'll be fast.

Notice that Spanish-language `ñ` is an odd case. With the general collation `ñ` and `n` are equal. But in Spanish lexicography, `ñ` is a different letter. So if you want an alphabetizing of Spanish place names you need the `utf8_spanish_ci` or `utf8mb4_spanish_ci` collation.

The good news for the code shown in your question is this: you don't need that `just_clean` function at all when you use the case-insensitive collation.

You may want to use  `WHERE City LIKE 'stratford%'` rather than `WHERE City = 'stratford'` to search -- this will allow your queries to match the first few characters of a search term. The `LIKE` construct will match `Stratford-upon-Avon` as well as `Stratfordshire`.

Comment: Hi Ollie At my age I need to take a deep breath... The table issues seem simple but what do I do to the script, as the function in the code above was just a try that I inserted. I can post the actual code and the table structure but how do I do that? "Answer your Question"  button below?

Comment: Don't use 'answer' to add information to your question, there's an edit button on your question :D

Comment: Can I upload a .png and a .zip files?

Comment: I'm a little confused over your 3 points. 1) utf8 seems to be the default and did not change anything: 2) seems to be working that way as I can type either way, capital letters or not 3) you say I don't have to do anything, but it does not work as I have it... I must have to do something in the script. No?

Comment: Hi Ollie. I've gone ahead and used a Copy table to test. I did the backup and applied the modify code you posted above. The 'City' changed from text to varchar (255): can't see any other changes. I then changed the name of the table in the script and tested with Sèvres. Results:Nothing!  What am I doing wrong? Did you see my script via the url I posted above?

Comment: I guess I must place the code above select _utf8'résumé' COLLATE utf8_general_ci = _utf8'resume' to this line $sql = "SELECT Image, Chain, Country, City, Top as '', Medium as '', Low as '' FROM Chains WHERE Country LIKE ? OR City LIKE ?"; // Your query string, but how?

Comment: This is where I am: running your code in the SQL query of phpMyadmin seems to have changed the collation for the table but not for the columns. I tried ALTER TABLE Copy CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; since this code and the city column changed from latin1_swedish_ci to mediumtext utf8_general_ci 
Now, I guess I have to marry this $sql = "SELECT Image, Chain, Country, City, Top as '', Medium as '', Low as '' FROM Chains WHERE Country LIKE ? OR City LIKE ?"; // with your piece of cade: select _utf8mb4'$city' COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci = _utf8mb4'$city'. I'm lost here...